# What does this piece of code mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

I am new to AS3. I was reading a piece of code on the web to help me with a project I'm working and I have a quick question on it.

```
public class MyClass extends Random {

            public var center:Number;

            public var radius:Number;

            public function MyClass(center:Number = 0.5, radius:Number = 0) {
                    this.center = center;
                    this.radius = radius;
            }

            override public final function random():Number {
                    if (radius) return radius * 2 * (Math.random() - 0.5) + center;
                    else return center;
            }
}
```

I don't understand what `if(radius)` would evaluate to. Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, the correct check should probably be if(!isNaN(radius))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(radius)`: A value of radius of zero evaluates to `false`; all other values evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Or in other words...

If radius is true or has a value.

Whereas...

```
if (!radius)
```

can be read as, if radius is false or has no value.